# How to get my USDT (ERC20) balance with web3.py + geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, python, usdt, tether

I have Geth in full node on my server and I want to get my USDT balance with web3.py.

Here is my Code:

```
from web3 import Web3
from ethtoken.abi import EIP20_ABI

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'))
tether_contract_address = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7')
contract = w3.eth.contract(tether_contract_address, abi=EIP20_ABI)
amount = contract.functions.balanceOf(Web3.toChecksumAddress(w3.eth.coinbase)).call()
```

But I get this result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1372, in call_contract_function
    output_data = decode_abi(output_types, return_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/eth_abi/abi.py", line 96, in decode_abi
    return decoder(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 118, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line 45, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 164, in decode
    yield decoder(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 118, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 186, in decode
    raw_data = self.read_data_from_stream(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 293, in read_data_from_stream
    raise InsufficientDataBytes(
eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1105, in call
    return call_contract_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1394, in call_contract_function
    raise BadFunctionCallOutput(msg) from e
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?
```

Also, my Geth synchronization is always between 50 and 100:

```
> eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
62
```

Comment: You need to wait until `eth.syncing` is `false`. Your node is not fully synced.

Answer (score -1):

you have to go to the ethereummain net and copy the abi of USDT and then paste it in your code and assign it to abi variable